# Checking OCaml type signature from C

Tags: c, ocaml

Let's say I have an OCaml function

```
let _ = register "cbf_coh_insert" (fun k v -> print_endline ("Inserted key=" ^ k ^ " value=" ^ v))
```

That is a function that takes two arguments. On the C side, I would call that with `caml_callback2(*caml_named_value("cbf_coh_insert"), k, v);`. Is there a way, on the C side, to check that the number of arguments (2 in this case) match? Other than I guess calling it and trying to trap a SIGSEGV. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: [some background](http://gaiustech.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/updated-maplistener-example/).

Answer (score 2):

NO WAI

This should be ensured at compile time (either manually or by code generation or by parsing and checking whether C and OCaml code are in sync)

UPDATE

Example register function :

```
let on_cbf_coh_insert (f : string -> string -> unit) = register "cbf_coh_insert" f
```

UPDATE

> I wish it was possible to pass a closure/let binding straight into C.

Why do you think it is not possible? Look at existing bindings that do this all the time.

BTW This question is a perfect illustration for [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I want to guard against the possibility of accidentally registering an update callback function (which has 3 arguments, key, old value and new value, and I call in the C with `caml_callback3`) as an insert, for example. Or delete which has only 1, the key.

Comment: I intend to supply the C bit as a "black box" that the OCaml user will not need to touch.

Comment: make special ocaml functions for registering callbacks with proper types

Comment: I thought of that, but remember that we have the function name as a string literal. The OCaml compiler can't "see" the assocation between the content of that string, and the actual name of a function in the code, you could register any function under any name.

Comment: The name can be anything and I might want to have several insert functions registered (on different Coherence caches). The name "cbf_coh_insert" shouldn't be hardcoded anywhere is my goal.

Comment: This name is only used as an identification for C side, it is definitely hardcoden. If the callbacks are not global, but tied to some ocaml value, then don't register them as globals, pass as regular values to C side.

Comment: OK, I will do some more research. The `caml_named_value` technique was the only one I could find in the documentation.